# how to make two services share a Devise authentication system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, authentication, devise

I have had a Rails app which authenticate users with Devise. It works well.

And my next task is to build a real-time chat room. Rails doesn't fit it, so I want to implement it on EventMachine.

But how to integrate the working devise authentication system into chat room? For example, in Rails I can get current user by simple:

```
current_user
```

How to implement it in another separate service(EM chat room in my case)? Of course, the backend of chat room can access Rails' database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say "Rails doesn't fit it"? Try to keep it all under one roof. As @Bob mentioned, there are some tools that will do just that.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub but also
http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

There are other ones as well that will integrate nicely with Rails. Otherwise, the question of EventMachine & Rails integration was asked before: [How do EventMachine & Rails integrate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570392/how-do-eventmachine-rails-integrate)